# How do I add a space between certain items in a navigation rail in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation

So I want the profile icon to be at the bottom of the navigation rail.
Here is my code:

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Namer App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var current = WordPair.random();

  void getNext() {
    current = WordPair.random();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  var favorites = <WordPair>[];

  void toggleFavorite() {
    if (favorites.contains(current)) {
      favorites.remove(current);
    } else {
      favorites.add(current);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget page;
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        page = GeneratorPage();
        break;
      case 1:
        page = FavoritesPage();
        break;
      case 2:
        page = ProfilePage();
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError('no widget for $selectedIndex');
    }

    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: NavigationRail(
                spacerIndex: 2,
                extended: constraints.maxWidth >= 600,
                destinations: [
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    label: Text('Home'),
                  ),
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                    label: Text('Favorites'),
                  ),
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    label: Text('Profile'),
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                child: page,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Sign Up!'),
    );
  }
}

class FavoritesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    if (appState.favorites.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('No favorites yet.'),
      );
    }

    return ListView(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Text('You have '
              '${appState.favorites.length} favorites:'),
        ),
        for (var pair in appState.favorites)
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: Text(pair.asLowerCase),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class GeneratorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    var pair = appState.current;

    IconData icon;
    if (appState.favorites.contains(pair)) {
      icon = Icons.favorite;
    } else {
      icon = Icons.favorite_border;
    }

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          BigCard(pair: pair),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  appState.toggleFavorite();
                },
                icon: Icon(icon),
                label: Text('Like'),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  appState.getNext();
                },
                child: Text('Next'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BigCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const BigCard({
    super.key,
    required this.pair,
  });

  final WordPair pair;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = Theme.of(context);
    var style = theme.textTheme.displayMedium!.copyWith(
      color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
    );
    return Card(
      color: theme.colorScheme.primary,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Text(
          pair.asLowerCase,
          style: style,
          semanticsLabel: "${pair.first} ${pair.second}",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using a spacer index (which I have included in the code above), but it just gives an error saying "The named parameter 'spacer Index' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'spacerlndex'"

Comment: There is no such property as spacer index in the NavigationRail widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html

Answer (score -2):

You can use a VerticalDivider() between each NavigationRailDestination like this:

```
NavigationRailDestination()
const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
NavigationRailDestination()
...
```

Comment: Doesn't work because of this build error: "The element type 'SizedBox' can't be assigned to the list type 'NavigationRailDestination'."

Comment: I have edited my answer check it out now